# PrimeNg Select SubItem of menu by default

Tags: angular, primeng

there's a way to preselect a SubItem of a menu by default. I'm using the component **p-panelMenu** but when I change any url path I lose the focus of the SubItem previous selected. So I need again to put the focus on the SubItem to preselect the subitem of the parent menu each time I change the URL. In the primeNg documentation I don't see any option to preselect a subItem of the menu.

Thank you very much

Comment: can u create a example so that question can be understandable?
create issue here?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes-pa6sj7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Now what I want is for example to preselect by default in the list of Items, that are the childs of the parent preselect the second SubItem in this case the label 'Open' so that the keep marked as selected.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes-pa6sj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Sorry I put the example but the app is not saving the changes

Comment: fork it and edit ur app

Comment: Okay Done - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes-2zkqof?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: please check here what u need to do here?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes-k6ytpi?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in style.css
as ur design

```
.ui-state-active {
  background: #d6d6d6;
}
```

ur array will be like this

```
 this.items = [
            {
                label: 'File',
                icon: 'pi pi-pw pi-file',
                items: [

                    {
                      label: 'Open', 
                      routerLink: ['/proposal/create'], 
                      routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
                      icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link'
                    },
                    {separator: true},
                    {
                      label: 'Quit',
                      routerLink: ['/proposal'],
                      routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },
                      icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

Hope this will solve. here is the reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-themes-k6ytpi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hello thank you very much but I dont understand where are you indicate the defult element selected in the menu??? routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true }, it is this???

Comment: actually with css only works 

.ui-state-active {
  background: #d6d6d6;
}

routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true },  for this will help u .. if ur router is users and users/list.. it will make ur route exact and active..